# Video editing: Two video windows

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In adobe premiere, I have two video editing windows within the same program. The window on the left allows me to scrub through any clip I choose, while the right side is the actual timeline view. Is there a way in blender to accomplish this?

Using 2.91.0 on Windows 10.[image: two screens]

Comment: VSEQF offers 3 point editing by using the Movie Clip Editor(you'll have to add it to the UI yourself): https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF

Alternatively you can load all footage into one scene and edit in another, like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1W7LHOhBx4